# Linux recognize only partial memory

Tags: linux, memory, graphics-card

I tried different linux distributions (Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome Remix, Fedora 18, Bridge Linux) on my new laptop but all of them have a problem with memory. My laptop has 4 GB memory but Ubuntu recognises only 2,4 GB. Obviously both BIOS and Windows 8 recognize all 4GB.

My laptop configuration: Lenovo B590 CPU: Intel Core i5-3210M Ram: 4 GB DDR3-SDRAM Chipset motherboard: Intel HM77 Express Integrated graphics: HD Graphics 4000.

It may be possible that the lost memory is borrowed from Intel HD Graphics? if it's true, it always borrows fixed maximum memory?!

Some useful command outputs:

```
midecode --type memory

Array Handle: 0x000B
Error Information Handle: Not Provided
Total Width: 64 bits
Data Width: 64 bits
Size: 4096 MB
Form Factor: SODIMM
Set: None
Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
Bank Locator: BANK 2
Type: DDR3
Type Detail: Synchronous
Speed: 1600 MHz
Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
Serial Number: 1A21B5B9
Asset Tag: 9876543210
Part Number: HMT351S6EFR8C-PB  
Rank: Unknown
Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
```

Output from `free -m`:

```
              total   used    free  shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2483    1136    1346       0         56        515
-/+ buffers/cache:     563    1919
Swap:         4884       0    4884
```

Output from `cat /proc/meminfo | grep "Mem*"`

```
MemTotal:        2542664 kB
MemFree:         1373552 kB
```

Output from `dmesg | grep -i memory`

```
[    0.000000] initial memory mapped: [mem 0x00000000-0x1fffffff]
[    0.000000] Base memory trampoline at [ffff880000097000] 97000 size 24576
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x00000000-0x846f1fff]
[    0.000000] init_memory_mapping: [mem 0x100000000-0x11e5fffff]
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009d000 - 00000000000a0000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000e0000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 0000000020000000 - 0000000020200000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 0000000040004000 - 0000000040005000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000846f2000 - 00000000dae9f000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000dae9f000 - 00000000daf9f000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000daf9f000 - 00000000dafff000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000dafff000 - 00000000dfa00000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000dfa00000 - 00000000f8000000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000f8000000 - 00000000fc000000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fc000000 - 00000000fe800000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fe800000 - 00000000fe810000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fe810000 - 00000000fec00000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fec00000 - 00000000fec01000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fec01000 - 00000000fed08000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fed08000 - 00000000fed09000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fed09000 - 00000000fed10000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fed10000 - 00000000fed1a000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fed1a000 - 00000000fed1c000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fed1c000 - 00000000fed20000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fed20000 - 00000000fee00000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fee00000 - 00000000fee01000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fee01000 - 00000000ffc20000
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000ffc20000 - 0000000100000000
[    0.000000] Memory: 2515460k/4691968k available (6711k kernel code, 2027016k absent, 149492k reserved, 6459k data, 928k init)
[    0.000000] please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
[    0.001851] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.522565] Freeing initrd memory: 23680k freed
[    1.430344] Freeing unused kernel memory: 928k freed
[    1.433360] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1472k freed
[    1.435653] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1124k freed
[    1.471316] pci 0000:00:00.0: >detected 65536K stolen memory
[   16.146844] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
```

`Linux antonio-Notebook 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP

Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
dmesg | grep BIOS-e820

[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009cfff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009d000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000001fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020000000-0x00000000201fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020200000-0x0000000040003fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040004000-0x0000000040004fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000040005000-0x00000000846f1fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000846f2000-0x00000000dae9efff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dae9f000-0x00000000daf9efff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000daf9f000-0x00000000daffefff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dafff000-0x00000000df9fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fe800000-0x00000000fe80ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed08000-0x00000000fed08fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed10000-0x00000000fed19fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed1ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ffc20000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000011e5fffff] usable
```

Comment: The lines `[    0.000000] Memory: 2515460k/4691968k available (6711k kernel code, 2027016k absent, 149492k reserved, 6459k data, 928k init)
` and `[    1.471316] pci 0000:00:00.0: >detected 65536K stolen memory` look most interesting.  Did you set your BIOS to allocate some RAM for your graphics card?

Comment: Did you try installing the distros or just the LiveCDs?

Comment: Yes that line is interesting negatively :S
Unfortunately there's no option into BIOS about Memory.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dmesg | grep BIOS-e820`?

Comment: I added it to the top

Comment: Your BIOS-provided memory map shows blocks totaling less than 3GB. This looks like a BIOS issue, though one Windows is somehow able to work around.

Comment: The problem disappeared with new kernel 3.8.0-19-generic.
Now the system recognize 3,7GB of Memory.
Thanks to everyone.